# Android change play button to stop and stop button to play

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm using this code so that when I press my play button it will change to a stop button. How do I change it back to the play button when I press it while it's displaying the stop button?

```
 final ImageView Play_button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);



            Play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

              Play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);

             }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very simple thing to do. Store the state of you button somewhere:

```
boolean isPlay = true;

final ImageView playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isPlay)
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);
        else
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
        isPlay = !isPlay;
    }

});
```

Comment: I get this error: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable isPlay inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: @user1300788 Define `boolean isPlay = true` as class member.

Comment: Oh, sorry. `isPlay` has to be a field (aka declared outside of the method) or be final. Choose whatever you want.

Comment: @zyngawow You use `stopicon` in both cases. Nothing's gonna change.

Comment: @Onik my bad. Not very relevant thought, I think it is quite obvious.

Comment: actually this wronge coz always isPlay = true, so it's gonna go to if statement always

Comment: I'm still not sure where to add boolean isPlay = true

Comment: public class YourActivity extends Activity { boolean isPlay = true; //CODE }

Comment: @NoXSaeeD Of course it is going to go the the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `if`...`else` condition in this case and I would also advice you to use a `boolean` variable to check if it is playing or not (if you are using media player then  you can also use `isPlaying()` method of media player class). but for ease I would advice following technique.

```
final ImageView Play_button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
boolean isPlaying = false;


        Play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(isPlaying){

               //You can add you code to change the icon to stop mode
               //and finally set the flag to false as it has stopped now
               isPlaying = false;

          }else {
               //Add you code here to change the icon back to play mode
               //and finally set the flag to true as it will be playing now.
               isPlaying = true;
          }
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use flag like this :

```
final ImageView Play_button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
boolean isPlayIcon = true;

        Play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(isPlayIcon){
              Play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);
              isPlayIcon = false;
          }esle{
            Play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
            isPlayIcon = true;
          }

         }
        });
```